# Strange behavior with simple C function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have 2 simple functions, one function inputs in the the  NxM array not including N+2 and M+2. So the original array must be surrounded by zeros and the other outputs the whole array. When the out function is called I have a very strange output:

[image]

But when I move the code to the main function everything is totally fine. I tried compiling this code in CodeBlocks and NetBeans.Behaviour is the same.
I don't know what's going on there. Can somebody explain?

```
.....
int main()
{
int array[N+2][M+2]={{0}};

local_in(N,M,array);
local_out(N,M,array);

return 0;
}

void local_in(int len, int len2,int arr[][len2])
{
   int i;
   int j;

   for(i = 1; i <= len; i++)
     for(j = 1; j <= len2; j++){
          scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);

    } 

}
void local_out(int len, int len2,int arr[][len2])
{
   int i;
   int j;

  for(i = 0; i < len+2; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < len2+2; j++)
            printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  } 
}
```

Comment: You have an off-by-one error in your `for` loops. You're going past the end of the array because of `i <= len`. You should be doing `for (i=0; i < len; ++i)`.

Comment: Also, it's hard to understand your output unless you also give the inputs.

Comment: @Ari The use of +2 in the array declarations means that the loops aren't actually wrong (not in that way at any rate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `local_*` functions pass the array as `int arr[][len2]`; but should use `int arr[][len2+2]` instead.

In general, the code should be much clearer if you passed the correct array dimensions around then implemented any policy on which items to read or write inside the `local_*` functions.

Comment: No I don't get any errors. simonc, you were right I added    int arr[][len2+2] . It seems to work fine.  I made such a stupid error.Thank your for you help.